# Writing Logstash config file

Tags: logstash

Hello and thank you for your time.
I need to create configuration file that this is the input:

> 2017-02-14T13:39:33+02:00 PulseSecure: 2017-02-14 13:39:33 - ive -
>   [10.16.4.225] dpnini(Users)[] - Testing Password realm restrictions
>   failed for dpnini/Users

and this is the required text file output:

> {"timestamp":"2017-02-14T13:39:33+02:00
>   ","vendor":"PulseSecure","localEventTime":"2017-02-14
>   13:39:33","userIP":"10.16.4.225","username":"dpnini","group":"Users","vpnMsg":"Testing
>   Password realm restrictions failed for dpnini/Users\r"}

All i know is that i start the logstash with "bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf"
also i know that the file that i need to change is YML file inside the config folder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logstash conf file (your logstash-simple.conf) is composed of three parts: input, filter, output. Input/output is source/destination of your data, while filter defines data transformation. 
Check elastic page for samples:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html

What you actually need to do, is to write grok pattern inside filter to split your text into tokens/fields that you have in your json. Simple description of grok:

http://logz.io/blog/logstash-grok/

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can you please tell me how can i input a txt file to Logstash and get an output file?

Comment: You can put any plugin into input/output section, one of them is 'file' plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html . Actually in previous link from elastic they use file as input in one theirs examples.